# Add conditions of carriage to the FedEx label

Tags: fedex

In order to pass FedEx certification for the shipment API, they requested the label to have conditions of carriage.

Here is exact response from the FedEx representative:

> The labels you forwarded still did not have any Conditions of carriage on them . this is what it should look like on the second part of the label (note this is a ss of a Spanish version)

Attached example was a copy of the text from here:
http://www.fedex.com/mx/services/nacional_terms.html

I also noticed that different services might have a different terms and conditions, so, wondering how should we handle it on our side? Should it be a custom text specified through CustomerSpecifiedDetail or is there is a way we could use some defaults?

Answer (score 0):

The presence of the Conditions of the Carriage on the Label depend on the LabelStockType(see FedEx xml guide) tag.

For example:

1. PAPPER_LATTER - will produce a labels without terms and conditions on it;
2. PAPER_8.5X11_TOP_HALF_LABEL - will produce the labels with terms and conditions on it.